# find the empty spots knowing 2 spots (without iterations)

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

Is it possible to solve this without iterating over the array?

Suppose I have an array having 4 slots, [] [] [] []

and I know 2 points [x] [x] [] [] , is it possible to have a formula that tells us the coordinates of the other two empty spots? (using a mathematical formula, (not if this then that or iterate and fin the empty spots)) I think in most cases we get lazy and instead of trying to find a real solution to problems we tend to do it the easy way, by using conditions and iterations :/

Comment: Here's a *mathematical formula* for you: ` {1,2,3,4} \ {1, 2}` - it expresses the result you seek as the difference between the set of all element indices in an array and the set of indices of occupied elements.  (NB I count from 1.)  Is it possible to implement that without iterating (or its weird cousin, recursion) ?  No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your not given enough information. You don't  know what the other two points should be. All you can tell with  A[x1][x2][][] is that the last two coordinated lie on a subset that is intersected be x1 and x2

Example 
Let Word be an array that give us a representation of a word in a book

Word [page][line][number of words into line]

Now if I only gave you the page of the book and the line in the page there's no way you can tell me the word you need more information

Comment: so it's not possible to guess? even If I place the words? If I apply a formula for placing the words on the page, then is it possible to guess where the words are not :/ ?
the formula is this : 
if id is the first spot, the second spot can either be (id +1)%4 or (id +2)%4

Comment: What do you mean guess? The main problem is the information your given as in the example if your given two pieces of information you can narrow it down to the line. But if I added information as in the word is 3 letters long I can narrow the gap down but note you will have to itterate through the array to check if each word fufills the condition of being less than 3 letters

Comment: you are ruight, its impossible. guess i'm going with the old way, thanks for your answer!

Comment: thought i could instantly find the answers without having to perform iterations :/

Comment: But Lets say your Array is A[x][y][z]. And you know x and y you still cant pin a point on z from that information all you can put it down to is that z lies on a line of points

Comment: See itterations will only be used if your supplying conditional information as in z is an even number or something like that. You still have to go through each element and check if its even and to do that you will have to itterate through each element.

Comment: Heres another example actually say you have a group of lockers (2x2 array Item[X][Y]) and your told the locker you want is on the first row so your given Item[1][Y] and then our told your item is round and black lets say. To find out which locker holds your item or to find a range of lockers that fufill the condition of it being your item you'd have to open each locker look in and check if its black and round (this is analogous to itterating through your array and applying if statements)